# Are negative reputation factors tracked separately?

Tags: discussion, reputation, post-ban

I am getting myself to better understand the reputation system and featured achievements (both good and bad) based on it. I must admit, I have just learned a question-asking  ban existed (as I never encountered it, or received such), and as far as I have read here, it seems to be caused by the user's reputation and mostly negative reputation changes.

Now, recently I received some negative reputation updates, due to some edits made by me — the questions I edited got removed, so the reputation from the edits I made were subtracted. This also happens if you have positive reputation to answers which get removed.

So, technically, it seems possible to receive a lot of negative reputation changes due to what I am calling *maintenance synchronization*. What I am asking is, is it possible such changes to be treated by the system as a reason for ban or being internally tagged as a **bad user**? If so, it seems wrong to me, since in such cases the victim users would have not done anything wrong, neither be responsible for other people questions being deleted. If not, maybe it is a good thing to keep such changes separately?

On the other hand - good users that have mostly positive reputation, will never encounter negative reputation amounts due to the maintenance synchronization. So, is it really an issue?

---

**Edit**

I must clarify - I am not asking personally for myself - for my lost edits. What I mean is that is it possible to get into trouble by losing for instance a (few) `+10` answers to question(s) being deleted ?

---

**Summary**

As per answers and comments below, it seems reputation reversal works like this:

- Positive amounts that are reversed (edits, positively scored answers to removed post) do not count as reputation loss and are OK
- Negative amounts that are reversed (removing own bad posts) restore lost reputation, but still count for receiving bans or punishments.

Comment: Go to your reputation tab, scroll down, and check the "show removed posts" box.

Comment: @Mysticial, Actually, that is how I found that I got some reputation deducted. I was asking if this could get me into trouble if the reputation amount is too big (like +10 answer getting lost to question deleted)

Comment: I doubt it will be held against you. You made a bunch of edits. They just happened to get deleted.

Comment: You're not going to get into trouble for losing rep when a question you answered or edited is deleted. You lose the rep, and that may push you below a privilege threshold, so you temporarily lose that privilege, but it doesn't contribute to a ban.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you for the answer, that's what I wanted to know

Comment: Bans don't have to do with reputation at all, going by what SE has said. It has to do with score on posts (so if you get 3 downvotes and 1 upvote, the system considers the -2 score instead of the +4 rep).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, deletions cause **reversals**. You do not *lose* reputation for an upvoted answer or a post you suggested an edit on being deleted. The reputation you had *gained earlier* gets reversed, as if it did not happened at all. The removal event is *only* there to indicate why you randomly lost reputation that day.

Basically, think of your reputation history like this:

```
May 1

+10     Upvote
+2      Edit
+5      Upvote
```

Now, say that the post you edited gets deleted on May 2:

```
May 1

+10     Upvote
+2      Edit
+5      Upvote

May 2

(The post you edited was removed.)
```

As you can see, you're basically just cancelling the original reputation action that occurred on May 1, and adding a "notification" of sorts on May 2 of what happened.

You might also be interested in [a feature request I made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) that might help clarify this.

Comment: OK, so I can assume a **reversal** is not the same as a bad reputation factor (downvote), and is not treated as indicator for a bad user. Still, is deleting own bad posts also deleting the negative reputation that may get you bans?

Comment: It reverses the negative reputation, yes, but the bans do not go by your reputation; they go by the *score* of your posts, and deleted posts count towards that as well.

Comment: Thanks, that completes the picture for me now.

Comment: +1 If you could get a dime for every time you answer one of these... :)

Answer (score 2):

You were not penalized, but the reputation you gain with the edit was reversed after the question/answer got deleted. I understand that the rationale behind that is that one doesn't deserve credit for embellishing something that deserves to be destroyed.

See [Lost reputation on an edited question that was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145630/lost-reputation-on-an-edited-question-that-was-deleted)

**Edit**

> Is it possible to get into trouble by losing for instance a (few) +10 answers to question(s) 
>   being deleted?

I don't have a canonical answer on that, but there is nothing bad if you have edited some questions that were deleted. Perhaps you edited a question for making it more attractive, but the OP deleted it after it got several downvotes. In that case, **you won't go to jail, but you will pass go without collecting +2.**

Comment: I added some clarifications to what I actually asked.

Comment: Thanks for your response too. Indeed, I will still need to "restore" the lost reputation if it is required by a privilege and the deducted amount causes me to lose it.